# SQLITE3 plugins for IntelliJ

Tags: python, database, sqlite, intellij-idea

I have a problem: how I can read `sqlite3` database file?

And over, is it possible to read these files by **IntelliJ** by some plugin?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://sqlitebrowser.org/ Used this. Works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much, if you want, you can write an answer and not a comment and then i approve you.

Answer (score 1):

About IntelliJ (Community Edition) I use an excellent plugin named **Database Navigator** (look at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator ).

It allows us to manage not only **SQLite** databases, but **Oracle**, **MySQL**, **PostgreSQL** and **Any JDBC source** too.

About standalone DB managers the one mentioned by @Goion is a very good starting point (look at https://sqlitebrowser.org).

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate has support for SQLite database. You can [add the SQLite database](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-sqlite-database) to your project and query database from the IDE.